# Parameterized/Prepared Statements usage pg-promise

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, koa, pg-promise

I'm using `koa v2` with `pg-promise`. I try to do a simple `SELECT 2 + 2;` within a Parameterized/Prepared Statement to test my setup:

```js
// http://127.0.0.1:3000/sql/2
router.get('/sql/:id', async (ctx) => {
  await db.any({
    name: 'addition',
    text: 'SELECT 2 + 2;',
  })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('DATA:', data);
      ctx.state = { title: data }; // => I want to return num 4 instead of [Object Object]
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('ERROR:', error);
      ctx.body = '::DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR::';
    })
    .finally(pgp.end);

  await ctx.render('index');
});
```

Which is rendering `[Object Object]` in the templates and returning this to the console from `pg-monitor`:

```bash
17:30:54 connect(postgres@postgres)
17:30:54 name="addition", text="SELECT 2 + 2;"
17:30:54 disconnect(postgres@postgres)
DATA: [ anonymous { '?column?': 4 } ]
```

**My problem:**

I want to store result `4` in `ctx.state`. I don't know how can I access it within `[ anonymous { '?column?': 4 } ]`?

Thank You for your help!

**Edit:**

I found another [recommended(1)](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Common-Mistakes#named-parameter-formatting-is-not-used-where-it-should-be) [ways(2)](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) to dealing with named parameters in the official wiki.

```js
// http://127.0.0.1:3000/sql/2
router.get('/sql/:id', async (ctx) => {
  const obj = {
    id: parseInt(ctx.params.id, 10),
  };
  await db.result('SELECT ${id} + ${id}', obj)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('DATA:', data.rows[0]['?column?']);
      ctx.state = { title: data.rows[0]['?column?'] }; // => 4
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('ERROR:', error);
      ctx.body = '::DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR::';
    })
    .finally(pgp.end);

  await ctx.render('index');
});
```

I changed the `any` object to `result`, which returning the raw text. Than I access number `4` like a javascript object. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to access this value?

What is the recommended, more faster, safer way of usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are requesting just one value, you should use method [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one):

```js
const {value} = await db.one({
    name: 'addition',
    text: 'SELECT 2 + 2 as value',
}); // value = 4
```

And for such example you cannot use types [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) or [ParameterizedQuery](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html), because they format query on the server side, and PostgreSQL does not support syntax like `$1 + $1`.

The real question is - do you really need those types?

Comment: I want to use a query method which is safe from sql injection. The best practices part in the API docs and reddit answers suggested this is the way to do it (so I don't know am I really need it or not). My app will not do any post requests at first (the DB will act like a json file or an API). The routing will decide what to be queried from the db (URL params). My 2nd example seems to me has a simple syntax. Do you have anything against it why you only recommended the first one?

Comment: `pg-promise` provides its own protection against SQL injection. For example, see [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) that you should use for any dynamic columns ;) There is nothing specific in the second example. And you should always name calculated columns, to be able to address them directly.

Comment: I ended up with this implementation: `db.one('SELECT ${id} + ${id} as VALUE;', { id: parseInt(ctx.params.id, 10) }, v => v.value)` and it's works. I left out `[]` and `+` before the `v.value`. What does the array `[]` and `+` do here?

Comment: `+` = `parseInt`, `[]` was an empty list of parameters.